# How to change baking(bake type) in light component in unity with code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got the problem when I wanted to change the bake type of light. In the inspector, I can choose realtime, baked or mixed and I cannot find a way to change it with a script. Can anyone help me? Thank a lot. By the way, I'm using unity 5.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** change baking(bake type) with *Unity 5.3.6*. You will need *Unity 5.5* version or above to do so. The answer below depends on the version you wish to update to.

For *Unity 5.5*, this can be done with the [`Light.lightmappingMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Light-lightmappingMode.html) property and [`LightmappingMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/LightmappingMode.html):

```
Light light = GetComponent<Light>();
light.lightmappingMode = LightmappingMode.Mixed;
```

For *Unity 5.6* and *above*, this can be done with [`Light.lightmapBakeType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-lightmapBakeType.html) and [`LightmapBakeType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LightmapBakeType.html):

```
Light light = GetComponent<Light>();
light.lightmapBakeType = LightmapBakeType.Mixed;
```

Comment: Yeah that's the only option. Although it's weird how Unity changed the way to do that between 5.5v and 5.6v and deprecated there other one quickly. Let me know if you update and still have issues